# Python replace integers by integers only at particular location

Tags: python, regex, replace

hi i have a file which contains the data as shown below. I want to replace the integers which occurs after 'A' (fourth column) 2,3,15,25,115,1215 with other integers which i have them in dictionary (key,value). the number of white spaces after 'A' ranges from 0-3. I tried str.replace(old,new) method in python but it replaces all instance of the integers in the file.
This is the replacement i want to do inside the file.

```
replacements = {2:0,3:5,15:7,25:30,115:120,1215:1220}

Name      1  N   ASHA A   2 35 23    
Name      2  R   MONA A   3 25 56    
Name      3  P   TERY A  15 23 32    
Name      4  Q   JACK A  25 56 25   
Name      5  D   TOM  A 115 57 45  
Name      3  P   SEN  A1215 45 56
```

Suggest me some ways to do it.

Comment: why there is not space at last ine b/w A and digit???

Comment: I think that's wrong. There sould be a space

Comment: op clearly mention that `the number of white spaces after 'A' ranges from 0-3`

Comment: I see that but it's still strange for me.

Comment: @Hackaholic ya there is no space for some lines for 4 digit integers.

Comment: Are each lines always the same length?  Is there any chance at all that you have the 'A' in the fourth column not be in the position with the same number of characters from the left/right as the other lines?

Comment: @zehnpaard "A" always be at the same location for example A always be at col23 in text file and the integers which follow A falls in 0-3 column after A.

Comment: Thanks.  Incidentally, is it ever possible for the last two numbers to be 3 digits?  Or are they always 2?  And the fourth column - can it extend beyond 4 characters?

Comment: @zehnpaard hi ya the last two numbers may be negative(-45) and they may be one/two/three digits integer or floats. But fourth column doesn''t extend beyond 4 digits after A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Editted based on additional info regarding all other numbers.**

This is entirely dependent on the specific characteristics of your file that you mention in your comments.

```
replacements = {2:0,3:5,15:7,25:30,115:120,1215:1220}

with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    pos_a = 22 # 0-indexed position of 'A' in every line
    for line in fin:
        left_side = line[:pos_a + 1]
        num_to_convert = line[pos_a + 1: pos_a + 5]
        right_side = line[pos_a + 5:]

        # String formatting to preserve padding as per original file
        newline = '{}{:>4}{}'.format(left_side, 
                                        replacements[int(num_to_convert)],
                                        right_side)
        fout.write(newline)
```

If there's a possibility that one of the values in the column will not be in your `replacements` dict, and you want to keep that value unchanged, then instead of `replacements[int(num1)]`, do `replacements.get(int(num1), num1)`

Comment: ya sometimes the last two numbers may be floats and few extra digits. few lines look like this                                                   "Name      3  P   SEN  A1215     -29.459  89.717  11.745  1.00 16.85     N"

Comment: The example has me confused, do you mean there are lines that have more than 3 numbers following 'A'?  What's the 'N' at the end?

Comment: ya i mean to say that after "A1215" or "A  15" there are more numbers with a alphabet at end :-) (few lines follow this format so i d'nt want them to be left out)

Comment: OK I've editted my answer so that those lines should work too.

Comment: Yes !! working :-) Thanks Zehnpaard for your time and help:-) Sorry i couldn't mark two asnwers as accepted :-(

Comment: i guess num_to_convert must be changed to num1 ??!!

Answer (score 2):

```
replacements = {2:0,3:5,15:7,25:30,115:120,1215:1220}

s="""Name      1  N   ASHA A   2 35 23
Name      2  R   MONA A   3 25 56
Name      3  P   TERY A  15 23 32
Name      4  Q   JACK A  25 56 25
Name      5  D   TOM  A 115 57 45
Name      3  P   SEN  A1215 45 56"""
res = []
for line in s.splitlines():
    spl = line.split()
    if len(spl) == 8:
        ints = map(int,spl[-3:])
        res.append(" ".join(spl[:-3]+[str(replacements.get(k, str(k))) for k in ints]))
    else:
        spl[-3] = spl[-3].replace("A","")
        ints = map(int,spl[-3:])
        res.append(" ".join(spl[:-3]+["A"]+[str(replacements.get(k, str(k))) for k in ints]))

print(res)

['Name 1 N ASHA A 0 35 23', 'Name 2 R MONA A 5 30 56', 'Name 3 P TERY A 7 23 32', 'Name 4 Q JACK A 30 56 30', 'Name 5 D TOM A 120 57 45', 'Name 3 P SEN A 1220 45 56']
```

Not sure if you want to use the data or write it to a file but if your file is like your example this will replace the digits from the dict, if the len of split is different we know we have a number and an `A` without a space so we replace .
There will also always be a space so if you write to file and have to work on the file again it will be a lot easier.

I would just remove the map and use strings as keys  and values unless you actually want ints.
If you want to keep the exact same format and only want to change the first number:

```
replacements = {"2":"0","3":"5","15":"7","25":"30","115":"120","1215":"1220"}

s="""Name      1  N   ASHA A   2 35 23
Name      2  R   MONA A   3 25 56
Name      3  P   TERY A  15 23 32
Name      4  Q   JACK A  25 56 25
Name      5  D   TOM  A 115 57 45
Name      3  P   SEN  A1215 45 56"""
res = []
for line in s.splitlines():
    spl = line.rsplit(None, 3)
    end = spl[-3:]
    if "A" == end[0][0]:
        k = end[0][1:]
        res.append(line.replace(k,replacements.get(k,k)))
    else:
        k = end[0]
        res.append(line.replace(k,replacements.get(k,k)))

print(res)

['Name      1  N   ASHA A   0 35 03', 'Name      2  R   MONA A   5 25 56', 'Name      3  P   TERY A  7 23 32', 'Name      4  Q   JACK A  30 56 30', 'Name      5  D   TOM  A 120 57 45', 'Name      3  P   SEN  A1220 45 56']
```

Comment: I think he wants the results padded

Comment: @abc123, I don't see any advantage having different spacing, I have added a space between all A's and numbers which I think is  more important and useful

Comment: Because the result isn't the same length.  The OP is doing Fixed Length String replacement.  The resulting string length should be the same.  I upvoted this because I think it's all good, but i believe you should space pad by 4.

Comment: @abc123, so you think I should keep `A1215` the same so it can be another pain in the neck the next time the OP wants to work on the data?

Comment: I presume that he's editing the data using a lookup table and then resubmitting the table.  If he owns the whole end of the pipeline then I more than agree with you.  But if he has to submit this back to someone, they likely expect it in the original format.  I suppose the OP needs to specify :)

Comment: @abc123, it is possible to keep the original format using another split but unless it is really necessary I would prefer to get the data in a nice format.

Comment: Hi yes as you specified its fixed length replacement so the replaced strings should follow original format . A1215 should be replaced to A1220

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Great work !! Thanks a lot buddy :-) can't i mark all three answers as accepted ??!! everything looks good in someway :-)

Answer (score 1):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qX6aY3/2)

```
^[\w\d\s]{23}([\d\s]{1,4}).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7EwMw1BQWKiJwsGC)

Note: This is more of a fixed length parsing

---

### Python

```
import re

replacements = {2:0,3:5,15:7,25:30,115:120,1215:1220}
searchString = "Name      1  N   ASHA A   2 35 23    "

replace_search = re.search('^[\w\d\s]{23}([\d\s]{1,4}).*$', searchString, re.IGNORECASE)

if replace_search:
    result = replace_search.group(1)

convert_result = int(result)
dictionary_lookup = int(replacements[convert_result])
replace_result = '% 4d' % dictionary_lookup
regex_replace = r"\g<1>" + replace_result + r"\g<3>"

line = re.sub(r"^([\w\d\s]{23})([\d\s]{1,4})(.*)$", regex_replace, searchString)

print(line)
```

Comment: yep i know the regex. How you could replace the dict items with their corresponding values?

Comment: writing that code now, sorry if it isn't helpful yet.  You didn't post the Regex in the OP so I didn't know you knew it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added python example (only 1 line)

Comment: @abc123 This works really great except for A1215 is replaced with a space "A 1220" instead of A1220 :-) thanks a lot.